# Assetic image filter and localized resources

Tags: symfony, localization, assetic

For one of our projects we have a couple of headers which are different for each locale. At this moment I'm using the assetic image function to load the correct image, like this:

```
{% image '@AgendaBundle/Resources/public/images/header_1.png' output='/images/header_1.png' %}
<a href="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}"><img src="{{ asset_url }}" class="mod-rounded" /></a>
{% endimage %}
```

To add a translated version of the headers, the only way to do this seems to be hardcoding the locale:

```
{% if app.request.locale == 'nl' %}

    {% image '@AgendaBundle/Resources/public/images/header_1.png' output='/images/header_1.png' %}
    <a href="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}"><img src="{{ asset_url }}" class="mod-rounded" /></a>
    {% endimage %}

{% else %}

    {% image '@AgendaBundle/Resources/public/images/header_1_en.png' output='/images/header_1_en.png' %}
    <a href="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}"><img src="{{ asset_url }}" class="mod-rounded" /></a>
    {% endimage %}

{% endif %}
```

This seems tedious, error prone and hard to maintain. Is there a better and more elegant solution available?